# angular-fullstack:endpoint generates: unknown provider

Tags: generator, angular-fullstack, yo

I have used angular-fullstack:route picture and angular-fullstack:endpoint bild.

But in my route controller I want to use the Bild Schema like this:

```
    angular.module('galleryApp')
  .controller('PictureEditCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Auth, Bild) {

    // Use the User $resource to fetch all users
 $scope.pictures = Bild.query();
  });
```

But I alway get the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: BildProvider <- Bild <- PictureEditCtrl
```

If I replace the Bild with the initial generate User class all works very well if I use my generated class it does not.

Does someone know how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need create a service

```
yo angular-fullstack:service Bild
```

and create a resource https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Example

```
'use strict';

(function() {

function BildResource($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/bilds/:id/:controller', {
    id: '@_id'
  });
}

angular.module('backApp.auth')
  .factory('Bild', BildResource);

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I would try it.